# How to wrap content in Popup window if the content extend beyond screen height?

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to create a pop-up window that contains a text view. I have set the window height to wrap content. The content of the text view is updated programmatically.

If the content of the text view is less than the screen height everything is fine. However if the content of the text view extends beyond the screen height, the pop-up window height does not extend beyond the screen size, but keeps at the maximum screen height.

The pop-up window extends Popup Window class with touch listener that enables it to move up and down in the screen. That's why I need to show the full extend of the text view content.

How to set the window size to wrap the entire content of the text view? I've tried many setting but to no avail. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: It will cause me a lot of choosing to change to scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to include an extra scroll view you can set the properties of scroll inside your textview itself by including maxlines or use use text.setScrollY(text.getLayout().getHeight())

Comment: I prefer to extend the pop-up window height without scrolling the text. Similar to the dictionary function in Google Play Books.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by manually update the pop up window's height.
First set the window layout mode to absolute.

```
setWindowLayoutMode(0, 0)
```